# How to select item(s) out of a FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to select items using FlatList like when you select multiple photos on your photo galery (in this case, I am using a flatlist with 2 rows like a grid of 2x10). I want to select (for example) 3 items using onLongPress.

Something like this, but with 2 rows.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

Every item *rendered* would have an `onLongPress`, and an `isPicked` property.

Initially, and in `renderItem()`, you would implement an if statement that either renders `checked square` or `empty square` every time an item executes executes; To indicate if the item is selected or not (based on `isPicked`).

`onLongPress` invokes `isPicked` and rerenders everything (to toggle the square). So if `isPicked` is true it becomes false, and if false becomes true. You can achieve that by simply doing this: `this.item.isPicked = !this.item.isPicked`

Finally on `Submit`, filter all your initial items (data) by the `isPicked === true` and hurrah, you will end up with the items that were selected !

Comment: @HansPiña No not right now, sorry. Give it a shot and let me know if you need help.